# How to remove elements from a LinkedList in Java? How to set the first element to be the head of the Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm learning Linked Lists, and I'm a bit confused by the Node that is created when the LinkedList is created in the first place. So I use an empty constructor just to create the List but it also creates the root node and sets "next" to "null", but then the initial value of "int data" is always "0", and I don't want that (if I do print details it prints the 0).

See the printing below the code, the initial 0 remains after new elements appear on the list. In fact, it continues to exist, which should not be the case.

Another thing, my remove function does not work, what is the issue?

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node root;//the beginning  - root element of type Node(check inner class below
    int size;//keeps track of the size of the list

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
        System.out.println(linkedList.getSize());
        System.out.println("Root: " + linkedList.root.getData());
        linkedList.prepend(234);
        linkedList.prepend(45);
        linkedList.prepend(33);
        linkedList.prepend(222);
        System.out.println("Root: " + linkedList.root);
        System.out.println(linkedList.printDetails());
        System.out.println(linkedList.getSize());
        System.out.println("Root: " + linkedList.root.getData());
        linkedList.remove(222);
        System.out.println("Root: " + linkedList.root.getData());
        linkedList.find(33).setData(34);
        System.out.println(linkedList.printDetails());
        System.out.println("Root: " + linkedList.root.getData());
        linkedList.append(6565);
        linkedList.append(144);
        System.out.println("Root: " + linkedList.root.getData());
        System.out.println(linkedList.getSize());
        System.out.println(linkedList.printDetails());
    }

    public LinkedList() {
        root = new Node();
        size = 0;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        System.out.println("Size: " + size);
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public StringBuilder printDetails() {
        System.out.print("Linked List: ");
        StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder("[");
        Node currentNode = this.root;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            details.append(currentNode.getData()).append(",");
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        details.deleteCharAt(details.length() - 1);
        details.append("]");
        return details;
    }

    public void prepend(int data) {
        this.root = new Node(data, root);
        this.size++;
    }

    public void append(int data) {
        Node currentNode = this.root;
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        while (currentNode.getNext() != null) {
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        currentNode.setNext(newNode);
        this.size++;
    }

    public Node find(int data) {
        Node currentNode = this.root;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            if (currentNode.getData() == data)
                return currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void remove(int data) {
        Node currentNode = this.root;
        Node previousNode = new Node();

        while (currentNode != null) {
            if (currentNode.getData() == data) {
                previousNode.setNext(currentNode.getNext());
                this.setSize(this.getSize() - 1);
                return;
            } else {
                previousNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Node {
        private int data;
        private Node next;

        public int getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            try {
                return next;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println((char[]) null);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        private Node() {
        }

        private Node(int data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        private Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

**The printing:**

```
Size: 0
0
Root: 0
Root: LinkedList$Node@548c4f57
Linked List: [222,33,45,234,0]
Size: 4
4
Root: 222
Size: 4
Root: 222
Linked List: [222,34,45,234,0]
Root: 222
Root: 222
Size: 5
5
Linked List: [222,34,45,234,0,6565,144]
```

Comment: If you want to both append *and* prepend, you should keep track of the start and end nodes of the list

Comment: @user can you explain why? The complexity of adding elements to LinkedList at the end is always n, when I prepend, I simply go to the end of the list and add an element; meanwhile, the complexity of prepending is always 1.

Comment: If you keep track of both ends, appending and prepending will both be O(1) because you don't have to traverse the whole list

Comment: okay, @user , I will consider it. But this doesn't resolve my main issue, does it?

Comment: No, it probably won't, I was just making a suggestion

Comment: To resolve the issue of 0 , you can make parameterized constructor : public LinkedList(int data) {
        root = new Node();
        size = data;
    }

Comment: I guess the first node is initialized to 0 because you are using ```int``` in ```node.data```. If you use ```Integers``` as the datat type of the list the node will initialize to null, I guess. Have you consider to create a class using a type variable like ```public class LinkedList<T>```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remove method's implementation does not take into consideration that `root` element can be the one which you wan't to remove. Append this to the head of your remove method

```java
  if (this.root.getData() == data) {
    this.root = this.root.getNext() != null
      ? this.root.getNext()
      : new Node();
  }
```

And about the fact that `data` is always initialized with 0. Im not sure if i understand the issue, what do you wan't it to be?

Answer (score 0):

In your remove method there were cases that you weren't taking into account, I have explained in the comments on the code. Here is a first approach

```
    public void remove(int data) {
        Node currentNode = this.root;
        Node previousNode = null;
        while (currentNode != null && currentNode.data != data) {
//Here we are searching if the element exists on the list
            previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        if (currentNode == null) //If we enter here, the element doesn't exist
        {
            System.out.println("Value not found");
        } else {
            int value = currentNode.data;
            if (previousNode == null) { //Check if the element is the first one in our list
                this.root = currentNode.next;
                this.setSize(this.getSize() - 1);
                return;
            }
            if (currentNode.next != null) { //Check if the element is the last one in our list
                previousNode.next = currentNode.next;
                System.out.println("Value " + value +  " found");

            } else {
                previousNode.next = null;
                System.out.println("Value " + value + " found");
            }
            this.setSize(this.getSize() - 1);
        }
    }
```

PS: You should keep track of both ends

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm afraid your code produces NullPointer Exception.